# How to print lines of a file that do not contain any of the strings from another file

Tags: python

I have two files and would like to find all the lines in the second file that don't contain any of the strings from the first using python.

file 1:

> ```
> Apples
> Frogs
> Beans
> Dogs
> Lemons
> Oranges
> ```

file 2:

> ```
> Frogs THAKJD
> Beans THSHSKOO
> Cats HHLFKDKDOS
> Dogs PHOODLLSI PSODIW
> Lemons OOPOETHTH ROROR
> Berries GGHLSKSKSJD JSJSJS
> Apples THKDHS
> Oranges EHTHTJEJ
> ```

Desired output:

```
Berries GGHLSKSKSJD JSJSJS
Cats HHLFKDKDOS
```

I started writing this script (below) but then realised that it prints out every line in the second file that doesn't contain each word from the first file, for every iteration of the first file. Can anyone help please?

```
import sys

headers = list()

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as search_list:
    for line in search_list:
        headers.append(line.rstrip())

for record in open(sys.argv[2], 'r'):
    for head in headers:
        if head not in record:
            print record
```

Comment: what is the `type of your file` ? for example csv, tsv ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a piece of code working:

```
expected_lines = [line.strip() for line in open('file1', 'r').readlines()]
absent_lines = []

for line in open('file2', 'r'):
    exists = False
    for expected in expected_lines:
        if expected in line:
            exists = True

    if not exists:
        absent_lines.append(line.strip())

print absent_lines
```

Ouput:

```
['Cats HHLFKDKDOS', 'Berries GGHLSKSKSJD JSJSJS']
```

---

### What it does

#### 1 Extract expected lines

```
expected_lines = [line.strip() for line in open('file1', 'r').readlines()]
```

This line create a list of all stripped lines in `file1` (stripped to remove `\n` at the end of each line)

#### 2. Init a output list

```
absent_lines = []
```

This is only the list where you will store lines you want to output

#### 3. Loop in file2 & look for absent lines

The for loop just iterate on lines in `file2` and check if no one expected lines from `file1` exists in current `file2` line.

Because you want to test if a set a words exists in a string, you have to loop over all set of words before being sure that any of theses words exists.

#### 4. If nothing matched, append to output list

```
    if not exists:
        absent_lines.append(line.strip())
```

---

If you don't want to store ouput but only print it, so you can just replace `absent_lines.append(line.strip())` by `print line`

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine, you just need to change your last `loop` :

```
for record in open(sys.argv[2], 'r'):
    if record.split()[0] not in headers:
        print(record.strip())

Cats HHLFKDKDOS
Berries GGHLSKSKSJD JSJSJS
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a regex union:

```
file_1 = """Apples
Frogs
Beans
Dogs
Lemons
Oranges"""

import re
avoid_words = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in file_1.splitlines()))
# Apples|Frogs|Beans|Dogs|Lemons|Oranges
```

and reject the lines that match this pattern:

```
file_2 = """Frogs THAKJD
Beans THSHSKOO
Cats HHLFKDKDOS
Dogs PHOODLLSI PSODIW
Lemons OOPOETHTH ROROR
Berries GGHLSKSKSJD JSJSJS
Apples THKDHS
Oranges EHTHTJEJ"""
selected_lines = [line for line in file_2.splitlines() if not avoid_words.match(line)]
# ['Cats HHLFKDKDOS', 'Berries GGHLSKSKSJD JSJSJS']
```

As a bonus, you could make sure that only the first word is considered with `'^'`:

```
avoid_words = re.compile('^('+'|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in file_1.splitlines())+')')
# ^(Apples|Frogs|Beans|Dogs|Lemons|Oranges)
```

or only complete words with `r'\b'` as word boundaries :

```
avoid_words = re.compile(r'\b('+'|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in file_1.splitlines())+r')\b')
# \b(Apples|Frogs|Beans|Dogs|Lemons|Oranges)\b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set operators

```
import sys

headings = set(open(sys.argv[1], "r").read().split('\n'))

for record in open(sys.argv[2], 'r'):
    r = set(record.split(' ')
    if len(headings.intersection(r)) == 0:
        print record
```